# file to linked list in C?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm new in C-programming and i can't resolve problem with error stack smashing detected

I need to read file to linked list. The file looks like this:

```
    chicago;addie;story begins here;-----#####-----------|-----#@$.#-----------|-----#####-----------
    houston;harvey;we got a problem;-----#####-----------|-----#---#-----------|-----#$--#-----------|---###--$##----------|---#--$-$-#----------|-###-#-##-#---######-|-#---#-##-#####--..#-|-#-$--$----------..#-|-#####-###-#@##--..#-|-----#-----#########-|-----#######---------
```

there are levels for game sokoban, (every level take one line)

i need to use function `load_levels()` which load all levels to linked list and the other `parse_level()` which receive one level as a parameter and parse level

can anybody help? It fails in load_levels(it's marked in source code with comment)

there is my source code:

```
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <curses.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <string.h>

    typedef struct level{
        char name[50];
        char password[50];
        char description[100];  
        char map[200];
        struct level *next_level;
    }LEVEL;

    LEVEL* parse_level(char *string) {

    char level_name[50];
    char level_password[50];
    char level_descrition[100];
    char level_map[200];

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    while (string[i] != ';') {
        level_name[j] = string[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    j = 0;
    while (string[i] != ';') {
        level_password[j] = string[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    j = 0;
    while (string[i] != ';') {
        level_descrition[j] = string[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    j = 0;
    while (string[i] != '\0') {
        level_map[j] = string[i];
        i++;
        j++;
    }
    j = 0;

    LEVEL *current;
    current = (LEVEL *) malloc(sizeof (LEVEL));
    if (current != NULL) {
        strncpy(current->name, level_name, strlen(level_name) + 1);
        strncpy(current->description, level_descrition, strlen(level_descrition) + 1);
        strncpy(current->password, level_password, strlen(level_password) + 1);
        strncpy(current->map, level_map, strlen(level_map) + 1);

        current->next_level = NULL;
    }
    return (current);
}

LEVEL* load_levels(char* file_path) {
FILE *fr;
    fr = fopen(file_path, "r");
    if (fr == NULL) {
        printw("ERROR: file no open\n");
        refresh();
        usleep(1000000);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    LEVEL *current;
    LEVEL *first;

#define MAX 1000
    char one_line[MAX];
    fgets(one_line, MAX, fr);

    first = current = parse_level(one_line);

    while (fgets(one_line, MAX, fr) != NULL) {

        printw("5");      
    refresh();
    usleep(1000000);


 // here it fails - stack smashing detected.     
        current->next_level = parse_level(one_line);

        printw("6");
    refresh();
    usleep(1000000);

        current = current->next_level;
        current->next_level = NULL;
    }

    fclose(fr);
    return (first);
}
```

**EDIT:** I updated code and question with current problem.

Comment: `i` is uninitialised.

Comment: ... and the usage of `strncpy()` is useless. `memcpy()` would do exactly the same here.

Comment: 3) and `number_of_levels` is uninitialised, 4) the usage of `feof()` is totally wrong, 5) you are using *the same* (and wrong) index `i`  as both target and source index in `level_password[i] = string[i];`

Comment: 6) your first pass to get the linecount is not needed. A linked list can be extended line by line. 7) the `fscnaf(fp, "%s", line); will break on the first space it encounters (the third line of your sample data), use fgets() instead (and handle the "\n" gracefully)

Comment: 8) the `load_levels()` functions returns *before* closing the file.

Comment: I'd love to understand why so many beginners misuse (abuse?) `feof()`.  It shouldn't even be mentioned, IMNSHO, but clearly it is described far too early in their training — is there a well-known book that advocates its misuse?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It are probably the dreaded Herb Schildt books that caused this plague (plus the `void main()` thing)

Comment: It appears to be a *pascalism*: http://community.freepascal.org/bboards/message?message_id=765479&forum_id=24082 (with different semantics) , so maybe Herb Schild c.s. were exposed to Pascal before "learning" C and writing books about it.

Comment: To the OP: the -> map field in the second string is larger than 200 and you are not testing its size before assigning. Also: you are not removing the "\r" and/or "\n".

Comment: @wildplasser: I wondered whether that author might be one of the (ir)responsible parties.  Surely...no, I guess 'surely' doesn't apply, but surely by now people have learned.  The trouble is that the students don't know; but what are instructors doing teaching from books like those.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: you probably know that Herb Schildt was effectively flamed to death by the c.l.c folks. But, unfortunately, he wears asbesthos suits under his leather jackets. IIRC, he has never corrected the known flaws in his books. http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/schildt.html

Comment: @wildplasser: Yup; I know of that site, and the ACCU too.  And the general opinion of his works.  I do have the Annotated C Standard, but that's primarily to get the left-hand pages which contain the C89 standard, not the right-hand pages which contain the (frequently faulty) annotations.  IIRC, you couldn't get a PDF for the standard at a reasonable price back then, unlike now.

Comment: To the OP: your update has some improvements (the i vs j indexes, you removed the feof()), but the parser will still fail on ill-formed input, for instance the loops  will run into outer space if a ';' cannot be found. Please see my answer for a more robust way of handling unexpected input.

Answer (score 1):

This `load_levels()` function reads the file in one sweep, and returns the resulting linked list. To spoil things, I changed some variable names, and removed the unrelated *curses* stuff.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct level{
    struct level *next;
    char name[50];
    char password[50];
    char description[100];
    char map[200];
    };

struct level *load_levels(char* file_path)
{
FILE *fp;
struct level *ret = NULL, **hnd = &ret;
size_t one, two, three, last, len;
char line[400];

fp = fopen(file_path, "r");
if (!fp ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: opening file \"%s\"\n", file_path);
    return NULL;
}

while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp)) {

      /* find position of first semicolon */
    for(one=0; line[one]; one++) {
            if (line[one] == ';') break;
        }
    if (!line[one]) {
         /* Maybe complain about incomplete line here */
        continue;
        }

      /* find the second semicolon */
    for(two =one+1; line[two]; two++) { if (line[two] == ';') break; }
    if (!line[two]) { continue; }

    for(three =two+1; line[three]; three++) { if (line[three] == ';') break; }
    if (!line[three]) { continue; }

    for(last =three+1; line[last]; last++) {
        if (line[last] == '\r' || line[last] == '\n') break;         
        }
    if (!line[last]) { continue; }

    *hnd = malloc(sizeof **hnd);
    if ( !*hnd) break;

#define MINLEN(a,b) ((a)<(b) ? (a) : (b))
    len = MINLEN(one, sizeof ret->name -1);
    memcpy( (*hnd)->name, line, len); (*hnd)->name[len] = 0;

    len = MINLEN(two-one, sizeof ret->password) -1;
    memcpy( (*hnd)->password, line+one+1, len); (*hnd)->password[len] = 0;

    len = MINLEN(three-two, sizeof ret->description) -1;
    memcpy( (*hnd)->description, line+two+1, len); (*hnd)->description[len] = 0;

    len = MINLEN(last-three, sizeof ret->map) -1;
    memcpy( (*hnd)->map, line+three+1, len); (*hnd)->map[len] = 0;
#undef MINLEN

    (*hnd)->next = NULL;
    hnd = &(*hnd)->next;
    }
fclose(fp);
return ret;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
struct level *lp;

for(lp = load_levels(argv[1]); lp; lp=lp->next) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%s!%s!%s!%s\n"
        , lp->name, lp->password, lp->description, lp->map);
        }
return 0;
}
```